Inverse topology for a compact left topological semigroup
Suppose $S$ is a compact $T_2$ left topological semigroup, meaning that $x\mapsto xb$ is a continuous function $S\to S$ for a fixed $b\in S$.
Is there (possibly after some forcing extension?) another, natural compact $T_2$ topology on $S$ which makes it a right topological semigroup? (I'm not sure what "natural" should mean, but I guess it should be functorial, and writing $F$ for the "inversion", we should have $S=F(F(S)^{op})^{op}$, where op is the opposite semigroup functor; it should also fix semitopological semigroups).
The motivation for the question is that there seems to be a symmetry between minimal left ideals and minimal right ideals. Namely:

Every left ideal contains a minimal left ideal (which is necessarily principal and closed).
Every right ideal contains a minimal right ideal (also necessarily principal, but typically not closed).
Every minimal left ideal is covered by minimal right ideals and vice versa.
The intersection of a minimal left ideal and a minimal right ideal is always nonempty and always a group.

Granted, this is not very strong evidence, but to me it is rather suggestive of some kind of symmetry that's been bugging me for a while. I don't even know if this is true for $\beta\mathbf N$ or $\beta\mathbf Z$ (note that each has a semigroup operation which makes it a left topological semigroup, and another which makes it a right topological semigroup, but we want the left and right topology to work for the same semigroup operation).
Edit: in fact, I just realised, I don't even know what happens when $S$ is a group. Do compact Hausdorff left topological groups have a natural right topological group topology?
